# Did Zolmy Khalilzad lobby for the Taliban in the 1990s?

Tags: united-states, afghanistan

Only [Pakistan, Turkmenistan, Saudi Arabia, and the United Arab Emirates (UAE)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Islamic_Emirate_of_Afghanistan_(1996%E2%80%932001)) recognized the legitimacy of the Taliban government in 1996-2001.

Many Afghans on Twitter and Facebook claim that [Zolmy Khalilzad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zalmay_Khalilzad#Taliban), the U.S Special Representative for Afghanistan reconciliation, lobbied in 1996-2001 that the USA recognize the Islamic Emirate of Afghanistan as the legitimate government of Afghanistan.

Did he do so?

Comment: It looks like during that period he was at RAND, and did a lot of writing, so that would be the place to start looking.